# How can I import data using query and group it by row values?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-query-language

I have a table with data which is structured like this:
[image: table1]

Is it possible to transform my table to table like this using `query`?
[image: table2]

Comment: Where is your trying code? Atleast please try again something and ask if any problem occur.

Comment: Take the [tour] and learn [ask] and provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a possibility of repeated weights, would need to do something like this

```
=ArrayFormula(query({row(A2:C5),A2:C5},"select Col3,max(Col4) group by Col1,Col3 pivot Col2"))
```

Comment: Yeah, weights could have its unique heights. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY(A1:C5,"Select max(C) group by B pivot A")
```

Or

```
=QUERY(A1:C5,"Select B, max(C) group by B pivot A")
```